# Best way to match a list of multi-word name strings against a master list in python

Tags: python

I've got a list of place names (~3000 lines) that were OCR sourced from a scanned index. I'm trying to clean the data by comparing it against a master place name list.

The input list names have multiple words and abbreviated words (eg. Pk. for Peak, Mt. for Mount, etc).

As suggested in the answers, abbreviated common words can be checked using  dictionary - but what is the most efficient way to test whether the multi-word names are in the master list?

Comment: Are the abbreviations in the master list? If so, you could just use a hashmap (dictionary). Everyone loves hashmaps (dictionaries)!

Comment: @numbers indeed. In python it's called a [*dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-dictionaries)

Comment: Good call.  I can add the abbreviations to a dictionary to optimise that check.  The main issue is the multiple word check where names are more than one word.  Anything more efficient than `for place_name in master_list`?